# Copy and paste with one double-click

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

ERROR MSG
[image]

they are wired up
[image]

I am creating a dictionary Italian (A)-English (B) in Access 2010. I created code to copy an ID from (A) mask with a double-click. (Through ID>property>on dblclick: event routine).

I need also that the copied ID is immediately pasted in a combobox of (B) mask called "cboinglese".

Here is my code. Don't notice too much some if and some password because I copied from the internet for a lot of it (VBA is not my usual programming language).

```vb
Private Sub ID_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    With Me.ID
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(.Text)
    End With
    If Me.ID.SelLength = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nessuna Password è stata generata!", vbCritical, "VERIFICA BENE"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        RunCommand acCmdCopy
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply needing the value from `ID` to be copied to the Combo Box named `cboinglese`, then you don't need to use the Windows clipboard at all.  You can simply do the following in the `ID_DblClick` event that you are using:

```
Me.cboinglese.Value = Me.ID.Value
```

That single line of code will transfer the value of `ID` to your Combo Box.

To prevent undesirable results if ID happened to be blank when it was double-clicked, you could enhance it to the following:

```
If Len(Me.ID.Value) > 0 Then
    Me.cboinglese.Value = Me.ID.Value
End If
```

That way the value of your Combo Box only gets updated when `ID` contains a value when it is double-clicked.

In general, you shouldn't need to copy your value to the Windows clipboard unless you needed to use that value in another application outside of your Microsoft Access application.

**UPDATE AFTER New Information from OP**

@tksweb4freelrn - You cannot put VBA code directly into the property dialog on the form.  You must remove that text from the property dialog and then click the elipses button and choose `Code Builder` to create a VBA Event Code in the module behind the form.

[image]

Then, you should be able to add the code above into the event procedure, which will look similar to this:

```
Private Sub ID_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    If Len(Me.Id.Value) > 0 Then
        Me.cboinglese.Value = Me.id.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, thanks sir... But i tried your code... it does not work neither simply pasting it in the double click event of the (A) ID neither pasting it as a coding line in the vba. How come? Could you keep helping me please? Thanks...and anyway, i'd like to thank you in a way to increase your feedback in this site...but i dont know how...tell me therefore !

Comment: @tksweb4freelrn what error did you receive when running the code? Please confirm that you are using a Microsoft Access form, and that `ID` is a Textbox and that `cboinglese` is a Combobox, and that the double-click event of the `ID` Textbox is wired up to run your code.  You may need to update your original question with more information, such as a screen capture or details about the error message received.

Comment: Thanks, sir. Yes sir, I absolutely confirm that: ID is a text box and CBO inglese is a combobox. As regards the fact of being wired up I added a new picture ("they are wired up") above and as regards the error message I added another picture above on the main post ("ERROR MSG)...could you let me know why it doesnt work? –

Comment: the error message in italian says: Impossible to find the object "Me"; if Me is a new macro or a new macro group please check that it has been saved or correctly typed.

Comment: thanks for all support, could you tell me how to give you a good feedback here?

Comment: If my answer is helpful, you should click the check mark to "accept" the answer and/or click the up arrow to upvote the answer.

Comment: an er occurred "impossible to find the method or the member of the data". in my opinion, you have to use the RunCommand...but the problem is, i cannot find or compose a code that  simultaneously copy and then paste the code in another item of the database.so i got stuck at the RunCommand acCmdCopy at the beginning of my question                                                                      
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ish1v1bM61cYjtM-bJ9SCv6BKvPBdjs-                                                                                                                   @Jericho Johnson

Answer (score 0):

I had the same request and found a solution with object Online. Just want to share here for other who may need this.

1. Create a table and a form with the field name Username.
2. Name the text box on a form as txtUsername.
3. On form properties, add below for the text box's double click event.
4. now you can double click the box and do Ctl + V and the value is pasted into a file or another program.
5. I made my form's text boxes locked so that I don't change values accidently when I double click. You can make another form for editing purpose.
6. in my example, you only need to change the text box name and form name if you already have a form created.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Private Sub txtUsername_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

Dim cUserName As String

cUserName = Forms!fLogins!txtUsername.Value

Dim DataObj As Object

'*** Using Late Binding to MSForms.DataObject

Set DataObj = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

With DataObj
.SetText cUserName
.PutInClipboard
End With

End Sub